# using PHP after Integrating Amazon SES with Sendmail

Tags: php, amazon-ses

Configured Amazon SES with sendmail on my ec2 instance as mentioned in the docs at 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/scripts-mtas-sendmail.html

was able to send mail succesfully using below line and i get the email into my gmail inbox,

```
sudo /usr/bin/sendmail -f from@example.com myemail@gmail.com
```

Now - when i send mail from PHP using

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

i get the email in the spam folder instead. how can i configure PHP to use the configured sendmail.

Comment: using php mail() there are lot many checks i need to perform to send html email. switched to phpmailer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the `From` address in the `$headers` argument?

The PHP `mail` function, doesn't accept a specified `$from` argument that marks the address of the sender.
Instead, you are supposed to use the `$headers` argument to configure the from address. See Example #2 here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: yeah, was using from in headers like in the docs. i found that the problem was while sending html email, not a plain email.

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,'-abc@domain.com');
```

If still facing same problem then please check your `$headers`

Comment: $headers - yes. I saw that i was able to send a simple email. The problem is that while using html email the mail goes to spam box in my gmail.. though i set the MIME type and charset as in php docs